# Data Model Version Compiler (MOMC) Error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Has anyone seen this and know how to fix it?

/Users/venerley/dev/Phase3-Dev-iOS-DB/WTInstrument.3/Persistence/DataBase/WTModel.xcdatamodeld:

Could not create bundle folder for versioned model at

'/Users/venerley/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WirelessTouch-gmsbhbucobwnlqcijbkyknnkktuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WirelessTouch.app/WTModel.momd'

This problem occurs when building for arm64 devices. Using Xcode Version 5.1 (5B130a) & iOS 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this makes sense to anyone? however this error message turned out to be a red herring.

The problem was due to the use of libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a not being built for arm64. When this was fixed the database problem disappeared too!

I would be interested to hear from anyone who can explain how/why the libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a file could interfere with the compilation of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Face the same problem

I just created new model with new name and copy all the entity from old model and paste in new model and deleted old model, it worked